# get unique viewers by page using Google analytics with php

Tags: php, google-analytics

I'm trying to get my visitor by url. Can I do that using PHP?
I'm searching docs related to this http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/, but it seems that there is no docs to do this kind of things.

Example:

`www.helloworld.com/users/adamramadhan => have 1082 page unique page view`.

How can I do that?
Thanks for looking in.
Adam Ramadhan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to request the `pagePath` dimension and `uniquePageviews` metric. The line from the example on the link you gave would be:

```
$ga->requestReportData(145141242,array('pagePath'),array('uniquePageviews'));
```

A complete list of available dimensions and metrics is available at http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDimensionsMetrics.html